# android app using reactnative fails to load

Tags: android, react-native

i build an android app using react-native and following https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

the app gets installed on device but shows a red screen with below

error:

```
Requiring unknown module "native-base".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".
unknownModuleError
    require.js:147
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:88
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:65
_require
    require.js:49
<unknown>
    index.android.js:18
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:58
_require
    require.js:49
global code
    require-0.js:1
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` and `react-native link` ?

Comment: yes i did as the doc said